# Solr and Unicode

Tags: unicode, solr

I've installed and configured Solr, Tika and tried indexing and search documents. Until now, everything worked fine. But, there is a problem with Unicode (of course :)). I indexed a document with Unicode text about Red Star (Црвена звезда) football club. When I try to search this article, and type "Црвена" or "звезда" Solr finds correct document.

How I can create synonym list for these words (or other Cyrillic words)? What do I have to do in order to enable Solr to find documents even if I type "звезде", "звезду", etc. ?

Best,
Joksimovic

Answer (score 0):

Solr provides an [interface for synonyms](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter) as well as a [SpellCheckComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent).

However your problem is not really related to an Unicode problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I tried to add these words in synonyms.txt and after that I could'n find the word I defined synonyms for. For example, I put  
"звезде", "звезду", "звездa" in this file, and I couldn't even find "звезде", which I could find before that. Do you maybe know what could be a problem?

Comment: without quotes and separated with a `,`. Did you also specify the synonymfilterfactory in your schema ?

Comment: yes, without quotes and separated with a ,. I think that I specified the synonymfilterfactory, but I can't check at this moment... I'm not sure fot that one.

Comment: I just checked, everything is configured like it should be.
class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory synonyms="synonym.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true".